# ModelState.AddModelError not showing any message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using telerik mvc grid. In my table I have unique key defined for a field. And in controller I am catching the error using try ... catch inside DbUpdateException.

in catch block I want to handle the error and show error messsage in view. So using following line,

```
ModelState.AddModelError("PROGRAM_ID", "Access for this program already exists.");
return View();
```

But this is not showing error message. Any idea why?

Comment: do you have property with name "PROGRAM_ID" in your model  too?
and make sure you have the validation helper call as suggested by Darin

Answer (score 12):

Make sure that you have a corresponding `ValidationMessage` in your view with the same key:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("PROGRAM_ID")
```

Comment: Oh then I guess that you are adding the model error to the wrong key. You probably have an array of those ids. Something like `ModelState.AddModelError("SomeCollection[2].PROGRAM_ID", "Access for this program already exists.");`. Of course all this will depend on your models.

Comment: no .. I double checked... property name is proper and also its a single value field not an array..

Answer (score 12):

ValidationSummary will only display ModelErrors for string.empty as the key.  To display an error added with ModelState.AddModelError in your validationsummary, change your code to:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Access for this program already exists.");
```

Comment: Follow 2 steps: (As suggested Darin)
1. In controller code add:  ModelState.AddModelError("PROGRAM_ID", "Error Msg");
2. In view: 
 @Html.ValidationMessage("PROGRAM_ID")

Answer (score 0):

Follow 2 steps: (Darin's solution works)

1. In controller add:  `ModelState.AddModelError("PROGRAM_ID", "Error Msg");`
2. In view add:  `@Html.ValidationMessage("PROGRAM_ID")`